# Liquibase: Cache for column

Tags: sql, liquibase

I would like do the following by using liquibase:

```
alter table SCHEMAX.TABLEX modify lob (COLUMNX)(CACHE);
```

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: That is highly DBMS specific. Which DBMS product  are you using? "SQL" is only a query language not the name of a database product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any kind of SQL in an [`sql` change set](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/sql.html):

Example:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sql-example">  
    <sql dbms="mysql">
        alter table SCHEMAX.TABLEX modify lob (COLUMNX)(CACHE);
    </sql>  
</changeSet>
```

you should specify the supported `dbms`, because the SQL might not execute on other DBMSs, as it might use vendor specific commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this sql then only executed when the dbms matches?

Comment: Found the answer: Yes, according to https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/sql.html